Error in building the .aab file with this command flutter build appbundle --release
Can someone help me in this when i run this command - flutter build appbundle --release and try to get .aab file in the terminal this shows error and i have no idea how to solve this
rajpurohittanu@Rajpurohits-Mac-mini vezigo-flutter % flutter build appbundle --release

Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
Font asset "CupertinoIcons.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 257628 to 988 bytes (99.6% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 3792 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             32.0s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

I have researched about this problem but nothing happens can anyone help me in this
Build.gradle
buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = "1.9.0"
   repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
}
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'


    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace = "com.arleven"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.arleven"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.22"
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[5.0.0, 5.99.99]'
    
}



flutter {
    source = "../.."
}





let me know if there is something version problem or anything else i didn't know

Have you tried running the command with the --stacktrace or --info or --debug  to get more information?

yes i have rajpurohittanu@RajpurohitsMini vezigo-flutter % flutter build appbundle --release --stacktrace
Could not find an option named "stacktrace".
Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.

You need to run the underlying gradle commands that flutter build appbundle --release triggers with the stacktrace/debug/info options.
